# Accessing localized files without using NSLocalizedStrings

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring

How can I access "Localized.strings" or any other localised file (created using the "Localize" feature in Xcode) without using `NSLocalizedStrings`.

My main goal is to switch between localizations on-the-fly while the app is running. I am aware of the *hack* to manually override the NSUserDefaults settings but it didn't really work for me …

```
var inputLocale:NSLocale = … //locale to use for translation
var inputLocaleLanguage = inputLocale.objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as String             
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject([inputLocaleLanguage], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

While it did change the defaults value, NSLocalizedStrings still provides the *wrong* strings :-/ Ideally I'd like to get a localised string for a specific locale I set (manually).

How can I access localized files without using NSLocalizedStrings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `NSBundle#localizedStringForKey`?

```
func getLocalizedString(key: String, lang: String, table: String? = nil) -> String? {
    return NSBundle(path: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(lang, ofType: "lproj")!)?
        .localizedStringForKey(key, value: nil, table: table)
}

println(getLocalizedString("foo", "ja", table: "Localized"))
println(getLocalizedString("foo", "en", table: "Localized"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find them like this:

```
let b = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let file = b.pathForResource("Localizeable", ofType: "strings", inDirectory: nil, forLocalization: "en")
```

assuming that you have placed them in the default places.